# VIM and NERD Tree - closing a buffer properly

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Does anyone know how to close a buffer in VIM when using NERDTree without messing up all your windows?  NERD Tree normally breaks up your display into two vertical windows (the browser on your left, and then your main window on the right).  If you close a buffer, then you are reduced to one giant file browsing window.  If you select another file, then it opens up a second window but separating it horizontally.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't use NERD Tree, but if I understand correctly, you wish to close a buffer without closing  a window. If my reasoning is correct, try this script.

```
" Delete buffer while keeping window layout (don't close buffer's windows).
" Version 2008-11-18 from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip165
if v:version < 700 || exists('loaded_bclose') || &cp
finish
endif
let loaded_bclose = 1
if !exists('bclose_multiple')
let bclose_multiple = 1
endif

" Display an error message.
function! s:Warn(msg)
echohl ErrorMsg
echomsg a:msg
echohl NONE
endfunction

" Command ':Bclose' executes ':bd' to delete buffer in current window.
" The window will show the alternate buffer (Ctrl-^) if it exists,
" or the previous buffer (:bp), or a blank buffer if no previous.
" Command ':Bclose!' is the same, but executes ':bd!' (discard changes).
" An optional argument can specify which buffer to close (name or number).
function! s:Bclose(bang, buffer)
if empty(a:buffer)
let btarget = bufnr('%')
elseif a:buffer =~ '^\d\+$'
let btarget = bufnr(str2nr(a:buffer))
else
let btarget = bufnr(a:buffer)
endif
if btarget < 0
call s:Warn('No matching buffer for '.a:buffer)
return
endif
if empty(a:bang) && getbufvar(btarget, '&modified')
call s:Warn('No write since last change for buffer '.btarget.' (use :Bclose!)')
return
endif
" Numbers of windows that view target buffer which we will delete.
let wnums = filter(range(1, winnr('$')), 'winbufnr(v:val) == btarget')
if !g:bclose_multiple && len(wnums) > 1
call s:Warn('Buffer is in multiple windows (use ":let bclose_multiple=1")')
return
endif
let wcurrent = winnr()
for w in wnums
execute w.'wincmd w'
let prevbuf = bufnr('#')
if prevbuf > 0 && buflisted(prevbuf) && prevbuf != w
buffer #
else
bprevious
endif
if btarget == bufnr('%')
" Numbers of listed buffers which are not the target to be deleted.
let blisted = filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val) && v:val != btarget')
" Listed, not target, and not displayed.
let bhidden = filter(copy(blisted), 'bufwinnr(v:val) < 0')
" Take the first buffer, if any (could be more intelligent).
let bjump = (bhidden + blisted + [-1])[0]
if bjump > 0
execute 'buffer '.bjump
else
execute 'enew'.a:bang
endif
endif
endfor
execute 'bdelete'.a:bang.' '.btarget
execute wcurrent.'wincmd w'
endfunction
command! -bang -complete=buffer -nargs=? Bclose call <SID>Bclose('<bang>', '<args>')
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>bd :Bclose<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>bD :Bclose!<CR>
```

Comment: awesome ... thats exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 35):

Try this mapping: `nnoremap <leader>q :bp<cr>:bd #<cr>`

Comment: Works great and so simple :)

Comment: Absolutely gorgeous solution. It was on the tip of my tongue.

Answer (score 10):

The [bufkill](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1147) plugin also seems to address this issue.

Answer (score 5):

`:bd` works for me in Vim 7.3 and NERDTree 4.1.0.

Comment: Hm, I'm on Vim 7.3 and NERDTree 4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 and I still have the OP's problem.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Vim 7.4, NERDTree 4.2.0 on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use
https://github.com/famiu/bufdelete.nvim

It'll keep your layouts intact when removing buffers.

[image: asciicast]